# How to add 'tweepy' to Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, twitter, tweepy

I wanna write a python code to create a twitter bot app in Visual Studio Code.
After importing `tweepy` it is not recognised.
I searched tweepy in extentions but nothing was found.

Comment: make sure you are in the correct environment. `import tweepy` is enough if installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add Python modules as extensions to VS Code, they are installed into your current Python environment (typically via `pip` from the command line). You might just need to select your Python interpreter from VS Code, however.

To do this, open the command pallet w/ <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd+Shift+P</kbd> if you're on a Mac), type in `Python interpreter` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should be able to select one from there.

If you have multiple versions of Python on your machine, make sure you select the one for which you ran `pip install tweepy`.

If you haven't already installed tweepy, you'll want to run the command `pip install tweepy` first.